# gcc (g++) How to link many libraries?

Tags: c++, linker

Is it possible to link all libraries (from the command line) in a single command? Such as gathering them in a file and supplying the file?

Comment: Yes. But yet, use a [Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).

Comment: you could use `make` to do this.

Comment: @usr Thanks. If you'll add it as an answer and add two or three lines about the reason for choosing the makefile route over a normal file, I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a script or a directly link via single command in the command line such as:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 hello_world.cpp -o hello_world

# Linking many libs
g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 hello_world.cpp -o hello_world -llib1 -llib2 -llib3
```

However, as your project grows in size with more source files, multiple sub-directories, linking with many system libraries, third party libraries, with dependencies between libraries and so on, the "command line" is impractical.

A [makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) is the way forward (you can also look at [`cmake`](https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/) too) for managing complexities. Even for trivial projects, a makefile is still useful (rather running a lengthy command line every time).